# Change prefix namespace WCF envelope request

Tags: c#, wcf, soap1.2

I have a question, I was wondering if is there an anyway to change the namespace prefix for the WCF Soap 1.2 request in c#?

I have tried to apply MessageFormatter, but this is just applied in the response structure, and I am looking for an option in the request.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MessageFormatter can be done on Server side also.And you can change this with MessageEncoder but it would cause many problems.

The link below tells you how to do this on server side using a MessageFormatter and also the downside of a MessageEncoder:
https://www.vanacosmin.ro/Articles/Read/WCFEnvelopeNamespacePrefix

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, for your comment, and this approch could be applied for the XML Client request?, currently I am bulding a WCF, but I need to change the namespace prefix for both, response XML and request XML, I have been using MessageFormatter to change the namespace in response, but I am not pretty sure, if this could be applied for XML request. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are two typical MessageFormatter definitions,The default MessageFormatter DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter and XMLSerializerOperationFormatter based on XMLSerializer.You can check it out and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

We might be talking about different things here. But you can change the namespace when creating the service reference in Visusal Studio.
[image]